# Modify Excel VBA code to paste into specific ppt slides

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I am new to the forum, and a few months new to VBA. All my coding experience is in Matlab, which so far I find much easier than VBA. I have read the forum rules, and searched for this answer high and low, but to no avail.

I am trying to paste different excel ranges into different slides of a PowerPoint. I want to modify the code below (taken in snipets from different forum answers) so that the range is pasted into the corresponding PowerPoint slide I denote, **regardless of what the active slide is.** I have tried "gotoslide" and that didn't work, and used ppviewnormal, but that also didn't work. This code will then be repeated for different ranges on different slides. So far the code will only work when I am on the slide it was written for, and I know it has to do with issues regarding the active slide, but cannot seem to figure out how to modify the code. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
' Desired Range in Excel to be copied into ppt
  Sheets("Summary").Activate
  Range("A5:H40").Select

' Initialize PowerPoint Object Library
Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
' Reference active presentation
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
' Denote slide where range is to be copied
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(5)

' Copy the range as a picture
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, _
    Format:=xlPicture

' Paste the range
PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
```

Comment: You have to `Set PPSlide` to the desired destination slide. Have you tried this yet?

Comment: Yes, isn't that what I have done above with "Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(5)"?

Comment: It is not clear that's what you intend, based on this statement "regardless of what the active slide is", because you didn't really describe the problem you're having in enough detail.  First, you will need to define a slide (which presumably you did do). Then you need to `GoToSlide` to that slide, **before** you can select a shape on that slide.  YOu can't select a shape on a non-active slide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove ".Select" from last line

This is shorter version of your code:

```
' Initialize PowerPoint Object Library
Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
' Reference active presentation
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation

' Copy the range as a picture
Sheets("Summary").Range("A5:H40").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
' Paste the range
PPPres.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste
```

Comment: Thank you! The reason I had select was because I then proceeded to modify the height, width, etc. of the picture I pasted, but I'll just do it a different way.