# Copy group from Excel to VBA

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I want to copy a group from Excel and paste it to PowerPoint slide using excel VBA. I used the following code to copy the group:

```
Worksheets(sheet).Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes(group_name).CopyPicture_
Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
```

But this code is giving an error. What is wrong with the code? How should i modify it to achieve the required? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need a reference to the Power Point application -> then paste whats been copied

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify Excel VBA code to paste into specific ppt slides](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664244/modify-excel-vba-code-to-paste-into-specific-ppt-slides)

Comment: i already have the reference, that is not the problem. Only this line is giving an error. The group is not getting copied only

Comment: i used the following code snippet(not writing the code to paste here):
                           ActiveSheet.Shapes(chart).Copy                    
But then its not getting copied as a picture. And if i am using the code given in the question to copy it as a picture, its giving object defined error

Answer (score 0):

I Just used

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(chart).CopyPicture
```

And i got the result!

Answer (score 0):

Or try this one, it works too:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Group_Name")).Select
Selection.Copy
```